# Merging PDF files with similar names

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, pdf, merge

I have a folder populated with PDF files in this format:

SI-T-xxxxxx.pdf
SI-T-xxxxxx-sol.pdf
SI-T-yyyyyy.pdf
SI-T-yyyyyy-sol.pdf
and so forth, with the middle part being digits.

I want a way for each pair of files to be merged in a single pdf, without the -sol

How can i do so in terminal? 
Thanks

Comment: For the merging part, I like to use `qpdf` which is quite reliable, versatile, and avaible on debian-like distros via `apt`, but the merge syntax itself is not that easy, so here it is: `qpdf --empty --pages SI-T-xxxxxx.pdf SI-T-xxxxxx-sol.pdf -- ./combined/SI-T-xxxxxx.pdf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pdfunite` utility seems to do what you're looking for (in Debian-like Linux distributions it is part of the `poppler-utils` package.

```
$ pdfunite a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf combined.pdf
```

Another option is GhostScript:

```
$ gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite =sOutputFile=combined.pdf a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf
```

ImageMagick also speaks GhostScript, so if you already are familiar with that:

```
$ convert a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf combined.pdf
```

Python also provides a PDF library, `pdftools`:

```
$ python3 pdftools/pdfmerge.py -o combined.pdf -d a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf
```

Regardless of which tool you use, we also need a way to pair off the files based on your described criteria.  This brace-expanded glob should get the first of each pair:

```
SI-T-*{0..9}.pdf
```

So we can loop over that:

```
for pdf in SI-T-*{0..9}.pdf; do
    stuff
done
```

We can procedurally determine what the second file name would be based on the first:

```
$ pdf1='SI-T-xxxxxx.pdf'
$ pdf2="$(basename "$pdf1" .pdf)-sol.pdf"
$ printf "%s %s" "$pdf1" "$pdf2"
$ SI-T-xxxxxx.pdf SI-T-xxxxxx-sol.pdf
```

So let's work that into our loop:

```
for pdf1 in SI-T-*{0..9}.pdf; do
    pdf2="$(basename "$pdf1" .pdf)-sol.pdf"
    pdf3="$(basename "$pdf1" .pdf)-combined.pdf"
    if ! [[ -r "$pdf2" ]]; then
        printf "%s not found to merge with %s; skipping" "$pdf2" "$pdf1" >&2        
    else
        convert "$pdf1" "$pdf2" "$pdf3"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @steeldriver That's exactly what i needed, thanks a lot.  Can you explain the syntax a bit? Kind of a Linux noob here ^^

Comment: Note that pdfunite breaks hyperlink. For better solutions, check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531215/34551

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [this longer post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531215/34551) if you want a more detailed discussion, but in short:

```
pdftk SI-T-xxxxxx.pdf SI-T-xxxxxx-sol.pdf cat output SI-T-xxxxxx-combined.pdf
```

will merge SI-T-xxxxxx.pdf and SI-T-xxxxxx-sol.pdf together into a file called  SI-T-xxxxxx-combined.pdf *while preserving hyperlinks*.

[pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) is open-source and [part of the debian distribution](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=pdftk).